# Help with integration using partial fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

I'm not sure how to get the values for $A$ and $B$ for the expression
$$
\frac{3}{x^2 - 16}.
$$
I've split the expression into
$$
\frac{A}{x - 4} + \frac{B}{x + 4}.
$$
I don't know what to do afterwards to get the values for $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply both sides of the equation
$$
\frac{3}{x^2 - 16} = \frac{A}{x - 4} + \frac{B}{x + 4}
$$
by $(x - 4)(x + 4)$ to clear denominators.  Now you have the polynomial equation
$$
3 = A(x + 4) + B(x - 4),
$$
which must hold **for all values of** $x$.  By evaluating at $x = 4$, you can find $A$, and by evaluating at $x = -4$, you can find $B$.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about this little time-saving trick. +1

Comment: It only works with linear factors of multiplicity $1$, though.

Comment: @SammyBlack: True, but if dealing say with denominator say $(x-1)^2(x-2)$ we can use the trick to get $2$ of the coefficients, and then the third one is easy.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{3}{x^2-16} = \frac{A}{x-4}+\frac{B}{x+4}$$
$$3 = A(x+4) + B(x-4)$$
$$0=(A+B)x + (4A - 4B - 3)$$
\begin{cases}A+B = 0 \\ 4A-4B-3 = 0\end{cases}

Answer (score 1):

Set the two expressions equal to each other, multiply by $x^2-16$, and gather like terms with a $0$ on one side of the equation. The coefficients of the polynomial on the other side should be equal to $0,$ which gives you a solvable linear system.

Answer (score 1):

Get a common denominator, add them, and equate the numerator to $3$. The numerator will have a constant term and an $x$ term, something like $Ux+V$.You want this to be equal to $3$, or in other words, $0x+3$. Set $U=0$ and $V=3$. This gives a system of 2 equations which you can solve to get $A$ and $B$. (Note: $U$ and $V$ will be linear combinations of $A$ and $B$).

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\frac{A}{x-4}+\frac{B}{x+4}=\frac{(A+B)x+4(A-B)}{x^2-16},
$$
we have
$$
\frac{3}{x^2-16}=\frac{A}{x-4}+\frac{B}{x+4} \iff A+B=0,\quad 4(A-B)=3,
$$
i.e.
$$
A=-B=\frac38.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{3 \over x^{2} - 16} = {A_{+} \over x - 4} + {A_{-} \over x + 4}}$
$$
A_{\pm} = \lim_{x \to \pm 4}\bracks{\pars{x \mp 4}\,{3 \over x^{2} - 16}}
=\lim_{x \to \pm 4}\pars{3 \over 2x} = \pm\,{3 \over 8}
\quad\imp\quad
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{rcr}
A_{+} & = & {3 \over 8}
\\
A_{-} & = & -\,{3 \over 8}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large
{3 \over x^{2} - 16}} = \color{#0000ff}{\large{3/8 \over x - 4} - {3/8 \over x + 4}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick for finding such numbers.
$$\frac{3}{x^2-16}=\frac{3}{(x-4)(x+4)}=\frac{A}{x-4}+\frac{B}{x+4}  $$ then
$$x-4=0 \rightarrow x=4 \Rightarrow \qquad A=\frac{3}{x+4}\Big |_{x=4}=\frac{3}{8}  $$
$$x+4=0 \rightarrow x=-4 \Rightarrow \qquad B=\frac{3}{x-4}\Big |_{x=-4}=\frac{3}{-8}  $$